# Observing "ended" media event on Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to observe the "ended" media event from a video playback. My plan is to trigger an action when  video.ended == true.

Here is the template code:

```
<div id="container">
    <video id="video" width="{{width}}" autoplay>
      <source src="shamman.mp4"
              type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    </video>
</div>
<content></content>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
Polymer({
  author: '',

  ready: function() {
    console.log(this.$.video.ended);

    var observer = new PathObserver(this.$, 'video.ended');
    observer.open(function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      console.log(oldValue);
    });

  }
});
```

The first console.log returns the initial value of ended, which is "false".
The second and third console.log are never executed.

Answer (score 1):

#### I think the most practical way of doing this is simply using the html5 api.

```
//..still in your ready:
var vid = this.$.video;
vid.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
     // do your thing here ...
     vid.removeEventListener('ended');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

As `ended` is an event and not an attribute that you're watching, you could either use javascript as in Todd's example or you could use polymer's event handling syntax (which has the advantage of automatically removing the event listener:

```
<div id="container">
    <video id="video" width="{{width}}" autoplay on-ended='{{videoEnded}}'>
      <source src="shamman.mp4"
              type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    </video>
</div>
<content></content>
```

Then just declare a videoEnded property on your polymer element definition.